# Manga about people that fight creatures for currency/points in a closed construction

Tags: story-identification, manga

I don't remember much about this manga as I probably read 3 chapters or less, probably around 5 years ago and I've been trying to find it for a while now.

The story revolves around humans that enter (I guess it was voluntary, but could be involuntarily as well) some kind of enormous laboratory with a forest like environment and they have to fight creatures for money or points.

The main character is a man who, as far as I remember, doesn't have much talent fighting the monsters, at least in the first chapters. Some characters are terrified of the monsters, but there are others (I guess some veterans at this) that fight them pretty easily.

Comment: Can you tell us about the art style? What about the fighting? Were they using guns, or was it more sword and sorcery? Is this an eco-dome or a magic dungeon?

Comment: Do you remember anything about how the MC looked like, e.g. the hair color or other unique identifying features?

Comment: Is the setting something like Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind?